# How can I prevent switching branch in git when there are untracked modifications?

Tags: git

Git does not allow switching to another branch if I have uncommitted changes that would be overwritten by the checkout.

Git will allow switching to another branch if the changes are not conflicting.

Is there a way to block switching branches even if the changes will not be overridden as a result? I would like to prevent an uncommitted change from being accidentally committed to the wrong branch.

Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: My question is somewhat related to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712267/2399186

Comment: Technically, nothing can prevent accidental commits on the wrong branch. Not to say it can't be *reduced* in different ways, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of, nor could I find, any configuration that would change how `checkout` works in this way.

You could write a script that checks for uncommitted changes and, only if there are none, calls `checkout`.  (For example, you could use `git diff --quiet HEAD` to verify that your worktree looks like the last commit, plus `git diff --quiet --cached HEAD` if you want to additionally be sure you haven't staged changes and then undone them in the worktree.)  Then you could alias that if you want, or just invoke it directly, to do "safer" branch checkouts.

The safest thing is to always check what you're about to commit (or, at least, what you're about to push; you can generally undo a commit pretty easily if you notice it's in error before pushing).

Answer (score 0):

As there is no `pre-checkout` hook, it's impossible to prevent switching branches. But Git has a `post-checkout` hook, which makes it possible to switch back to the previous branch/state automatically when there is one or more untracked files.

Here's a sample of `post-checkout`. Deploy it under `.git/hooks` and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=$(git config --get my.foo)
if [[ "$foo" = "yes" ]];then
    exit 0
fi

oldref=$1
newref=$2
flag=$3
if [[ "$flag" -eq 1 ]] && [[ "$(git status --porcelain | grep -oe '^??' | uniq)" = ?? ]];then
    echo "There are untracked files. Go back to the previous state."
    git -c my.foo=yes checkout -
fi
exit 0
```

1. `flag` is 1 when checking out a branch, and 0 when checking out
   files.
2. `??` is the status for untracked files.
3. `-c my.foo=yes` prevents invoking `post-checkout` infinitively. In case you want to bypass this `post-checkout`, run `git -c my.foo=yes checkout ...`. You can name `my.foo` whatever is different from any existing configuration variable.
4. `git checkout -` is a shortcut to go back to the previous state.