# Checkout another branch and not commit the code, can I get the code before checkout

Tags: git

I checkout another branch (branch2) and forget to commit the code (in branch1), when I checkout this branch (branch1) again the code have lost. How can I get the code before checkout?

Comment: By default git [won't let you switch branches when that would overwrite uncommited changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712166/switching-branches-in-git-with-working-directory-not-clean). What have you done to still be able to?

Comment: Chances are your changes are really gone and git can't help you get it back. But if you use an IDE with a "local history" feature (such as all IntelliJ based IDEs like IDEA) then you might be able to find your changes in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git checkout branch after git add, seems not update index and working area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450004/git-checkout-branch-after-git-add-seems-not-update-index-and-working-area)

Comment: Thanks @JoachimSauer, I use Android Studio and the old code still have in Local History

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320608/changing-branches-does-not-discard-local-changes

Comment: Don't put Solved in the title. If the problem is solved, accept an answer, give a different answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you did a reset first the changes should still be there.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one situation, where `git` will silently "forget" the changes in a staged file when you change branches : when the staged file has exactly the same content as the file in the target branch.

In that case, `git` will allow you to switch branches, and will keep the same content for that file -- which therefore will not appear as modified anymore.

If you want to switch back to your original branch, the burden falls on you to identify what files should be taken back from that other branch ; but at least, they should have the content you expect.

---

This is a reason why you will see recommendations to commit your changes, or at least stash them away (using `git stash`) before changing branches.

---

There is another corner case, which may mess with the content of files on your disk when switching branches :

- if file `foo.txt` is ignored (by a `.gitignore` rule) on branch `A`,
- and file `foo.txt` exists and is versioned in branch `B`,

then switching to branch `B` from branch `A` will silently replace the content of `foo.txt` with its versioned content (tested with `git 2.33`, this happens with both `git checkout` and `git switch`).

I haven't read the code for other possible corner cases, testing some basic cases on my machine indicate that `git` doesn't try anything more complex ; if there are any other kind of modifications to a file, `git checkout` or `git switch` should error with an explicit message.